# file transfer from DBFS to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, apache-spark-sql, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I need to transfer the files in the below dbfs file system path:

```
%fs ls /FileStore/tables/26AS_report/customer_monthly_running_report/parts/
```

To the below Azure Blob

```py
dbutils.fs.ls("wasbs://"+blob.storage_account_container+"@"
  + blob.storage_account_name+".blob.core.windows.net/")
```

WHAT SERIES OF STEPS SHOULD I FOLLOW? Pls suggest

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to load the data into a dataframe and then to write that dataframe into the target.

```py
df = spark.read.format(format).load("dbfs://FileStore/tables/26AS_report/customer_monthly_running_report/parts/*")
df.write.format(format).save("wasbs://"+blob.storage_account_container+"@" + blob.storage_account_name+".blob.core.windows.net/")
```

You will have to replace "format" with the source file format and the format you want in the target folder.

Keep in mind that if you do not want to do any transformations to the data but to just move it, it will most likely be more efficient not to use pyspark but to just use the az-copy command line tool. You can also run that in Databricks with the `%sh` magic command if needed.